# how to fetch data from stored procedure in oracle

Tags: json, oracle, symfony, stored-procedures, jsonp

what i need to fetch data from stored procedures

syntax in sql developer

```
 select abc_web_demo.wwv_json_data.dashboards('abc','7','tt',1211) from dual
```

returns json string

```
  {"data":[{"logs":7,"to_abc":88,"to_cl":12,"to_me":0}]}
```

code

```
 $tns = "
 (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =ABC)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = AAA))
 )
   ";

 try {
$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, '**', '**');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo 'Connected to database';

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }
    $sql = "CALL abc_web_demo.wwv_json_data.dashboards('ABC','79','Y',121221) ";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $te=$stmt->execute();

//$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT @NEW_ID");
//$id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

print_r($te);
```

Problem

- i have google & found i need to pass in string in query
  like $stmt = $connection->query("SELECT @NEW_ID");
- here in my my case i need to  pass 4 parameters in procedure.
- i new in stored procedures i need help how to pass 4 arguments in procedure .
- how to access json response using fetch statement.
- i need json repsonse from fetch data.
- any help much appreciated

Solution i tried

```
 $output = $conn->query("select 'abc', '7' ")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 var_dump($output);
```

Error

```
    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 923 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

when i tried test query it works

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from customers");
$st=$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: you have to fix that "select 'abc', '7' ", it's syntactically incorrect,

Comment: you wrote the proper command already above: "select abc_web_demo.wwv_json_data.dashboards('abc','7','tt',1211) from dual"

Comment: assuming you want to fetch it only for one row, not in a loop

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("ALL abc_web_demo.wwv_json_data.dashboards('ABC','79','Y',121221)");
$st=$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);

Comment: why this procedure throwing error

Comment: because you want to "fetch" out a procedure's result. if you're replacing the "select * from customer" in "$stmt = $conn->prepare(..)"  to "select abc_web_demo.wwv_json_data.dashboards('abc','7','tt',1211) from dual" , it will work

Comment: you could insert the result of the proc into some table , and then fetch from that table

Answer (score 0):

Write your query as follows. The `FROM` clause is mandatory in Oracle dialect of SQL.

```
select 'abc', '7' from dual
```